# Adding a unique ID field to identify spreadsheets imported from different Excel files with VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, import, vba

I have 2 questions relating to the title, one more essential than the other. I am using the following code to import all excel files within a folder to my MS Access database:

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function importExcelSheets(Directory As String, TableName As String) As Long
On Error Resume Next
Dim strDir As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim I As Long
I = 0

If Left(Directory, 1) <> "\" Then
   strDir = Directory & "\"
Else
   strDir = Directory
End If
strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.XLSX")
While strFile <> ""
    I = I + 1
    strFile = strDir & strFile
    Debug.Print "importing " & strFile
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , TableName, strFile, True, Range:="Sheet1!K:AP"
    strFile = Dir()

Wend
importExcelSheets = I
End Function
```

**1)** My first and more crucial problem, is that I have no way of identifying which file is which in the table that has received all the imports from Excel, as the files do not include a date field. The spreadsheets I am importing will be produced on a daily basis, so I want to create an additional column in the MS Access table with a section taken from the name of the Excel file, which contains the date it was produced on. The Excel files to be imported will be formatted as "FD Worksheet 01 06 2016", with the date section of the name relating to the date it was created.

Could someone show me how I would go about modifying my code for this? Ideally I would like to save the new date field with a "/" between the date/month/year so as it's formatted correctly.

**2)** My second and less important question; is it possible to only import specific fields? My code above is only able to import fields between two columns, and not specific ones. I would only need columns 'K', 'N', 'AO', and 'AP'(Col numbers 11, 14, 41, 42), as this would vastly reduce the size of the imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final working code is below, solution was found using HansUp's help:

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function importExcelSheets1()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim astrPieces() As String
Dim dteFileDate As Date
Dim strDir As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strInsert As String

Dim Directory As String
Dim TableName As String

Directory = "F:\FD Worksheets\JUN 2016"
TableName = "FD_Worksheet_Master"

Dim strTable As String
Dim I As Long
I = 0

If Right(Directory, 1) <> "\" Then
   strDir = Directory & "\"
Else
   strDir = Directory
End If
strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.XLSX")
While strFile <> ""
    I = I + 1
    Debug.Print "importing " & strFile

If Not strDir Like "*\" Then
    strDir = strDir & "\"
End If
strInsert = "INSERT INTO FD_Worksheet_master (file_date, Prod, Average_Cost, WSP, RRP)" & vbCrLf & _
"SELECT [which_date] as file_date, xl.Prod, xl.Average_Cost, xl.WSP, xl.RRP" & vbCrLf & _
"FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=" & strDir & strFile & "].[Sheet1$] AS xl;"
Debug.Print strInsert
astrPieces = Split(Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 5), " ")
dteFileDate = DateSerial(Val(astrPieces(4)), astrPieces(3), astrPieces(2))
Debug.Print dteFileDate
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strInsert)
qdf.Parameters("which_date").Value = dteFileDate
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError

     strFile = Dir()
Wend

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual workflow, solving both your questions, uses a temporary table that has the same structure as the Excel files:

For each file

1. clear temp table
2. import Excel file into temp table
3. Use an append query to copy selected fields plus additional information (like a date, or the file name) into the actual production table.

Alternative for steps 1+2: Link the Excel file instead of importing it
(`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink`).

Then the Append query selects from the linked table.

---

Unrelated:

```
If Left(Directory, 1) <> "\" Then
```

should be

```
If Right(Directory, 1) <> "\" Then
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Access "append query" with your worksheet as its data source.  That way you can import only the columns you need, and you can also extract the date from the workbook file name and use it for a query parameter.

In this example, I import only one XLSX file.  My Access destination table, "FD_Worksheet_master", includes a Date/Time field named "file_date".  And the Excel data I want to import is in a worksheet named "Sheet1".

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim astrPieces() As String
Dim dteFileDate As Date
Dim strDir As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strInsert As String

strDir = "C:\Users\hans\Documents\"
strFile = "FD Worksheet 01 06 2016.xlsx"

If Not strDir Like "*\" Then
    strDir = strDir & "\"
End If
strInsert = "INSERT INTO FD_Worksheet_master (file_date, Annual, Monthly, Hourly)" & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT [which_date] as file_date, xl.Annual, xl.Monthly, xl.Hourly" & vbCrLf & _
    "FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=" & strDir & strFile & "].[Sheet1$] AS xl;"
Debug.Print strInsert
astrPieces = Split(strFile, " ")
' Note: I assumed "01 06 2016" is "mm dd yyyy" format.
' If actually "dd mm yyyy", swap the order of astrPieces(2) and astrPieces(3)
dteFileDate = DateSerial(Val(astrPieces(4)), astrPieces(2), astrPieces(3))
Debug.Print dteFileDate
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strInsert)
qdf.Parameters("which_date").Value = dteFileDate
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
```

You may need to change the `IMEX` value; if 2 doesn't work, try 1.

Comment: Many thanks Hans! After a very small modification to your code, I managed to get it to work perfectly for me. It is now placing the date from the Excel file name into the 'file_date' field within the 'FD_Worksheet_master' table for every row in the original spreadsheet. From here, do you know how I would import the columns 'K', 'N', 'AO', and 'AP' from Sheet1 of the worksheet? I'm very new to MS Access VBA, so please forgive my lack of ability!

Comment: I used `HDR=YES` in the query's connection to the workbook because you had True for the *HasFieldNames* parameter with `TransferSpreadsheet`.  So that means the field/column names/headers should be present in the first row of the worksheet.  Look up the names for those columns and substitute those where I had `xl.Annual, xl.Monthly, xl.Hourly` in my query.

Comment: If I misunderstood your situation, and you don't have names/headers in the first spreadsheet row, make another query which is just `SELECT *` with your working `FROM` clause and `HDR=NO`.  When you run that query, Access will assign names ... such as `F1`, `F2`, etc. ... to the columns.  Find out which names correspond to the columns you want, and use those names in the main query.

Comment: Again Hans, your solution worked perfectly. I added my column names to the code and it brought everything in as I wanted.I will post my final code below. Thank you!